# Nginx redirect to another port of the exactly same host

Tags: docker, nginx, https, ssl-certificate, nginx-reverse-proxy

I use Nginx in container to expose Django service from another container. Additionally I need to ensure next interesting points:

1. Nginx must expose http and https ports
2. http traffic must be redirected to http port if sent to https
3. TLS certificate is only for one host name
4. Host system has same host name (domain)
5. Same host name is used in Django ALLOWED_HOSTS and should not be changed (preferably)

The main question I cannot find answer is that whether Nginx can redirect traffic to another port/service or same service port in the exactly same network space?

Why it is so important to me:

- the host with host name `H` already runs some services on many ports
- to use containers (deployed on the host) from Internet I need to call them using same host name `H`
- if inside Nginx I will redirect wrong `http->https` request as `H:443 -> H:80` (just to another container port and with exactly same host name) then it redirects to port 80 of the host, not the container!
- I can set special `server_name` for at least `http` server and redirect like `return http://http-server:80` but it will break `ALLOWED_HOSTS` and produce *strange* host name on some requests, that's why I need to use `H` host name for 80 port too

How would u solve this case?

My base `nginx.conf`:

```
server {

    listen 80;

    listen 443 ssl;  # <--- exposed to public
    
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/certs/${NGINX_CERT};
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/certs/${NGINX_CERT_KEY}; 

    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
    ssl_session_timeout  10m;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    root /public/;
    index index.html;

    client_max_body_size 2500M;

    server_name H;

    # redirect to http on mismatches (how to redirect to same services?)
    error_page 497 http://default-server:80$request_uri;

    location / {
        proxy_read_timeout 600s;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Referrer $http_referer;
        proxy_set_header Referer $http_referer;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_pass http://django-host:5000;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

}
```

Comment: `The main question I cannot find answer is that whether Nginx can redirect traffic to another port/service or same service port in the exactly same network space?` Nginx can proxy to any IP address it can reach. The network "space" (whatever this is) doesn't matter.

Comment: @tkausl exactly true, but how to do this WITHOUT changing target host name? I cannot just redirect to its ip or localhost because it will break other services; also I cannot redirect to same host name because it will be redirected to host ports, not container ports. I need some feature which performs redirection to the *closest* host with same hostname or exactly same host with only port changing